# Hibernate retrieving dirty object

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm facing problems with hibernate that sounds to be related to object caching.

Destilling the problem, I have an entity, lets call it A, with a list attribute mapped with `@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="attribute")`. The objects on the list are entities of class B and has a bidirectional relationanship with A. So B has an attribute that points to A mapped with `@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)`. I get the object A from database and add a new object B to A's list and call `session.update(A)`.

The problem emerges when I get all A objects calling `session.createCriteria(A.class).list();`, access exactly the A object I updated and the B object I added is not present in the list.

I tried to call `session.refresh(A)` after update A, but the problme still persists.

Does anyboy know how to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="attribute") on A class to map to B elements  and on B you have @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE) element => it's not coherent.

You should have a @ManyToOne on class B.

You can see an example here: http://fruzenshtein.com/bidirectional-many-to-one-association/

And if you want to add a new B object, you need to deal with id because of the bidirectionnal link.

"I get the object A from database and add a new object B" => B has the link to A ? If not the bidirectionnal link is not respected.

EDIT: you can see some explanation here http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany

"As the relationship is bi-directional so as the application updates one side of the relationship, the other side should also get updated, and be in synch. In JPA, as in Java in general it is the responsibility of the application, or the object model to maintain relationships. If your application adds to one side of a relationship, then it must add to the other side."

Comment: You are right. I replaced OneToOne by OneToMany, but the problem still persists.

Comment: I have completed the answer

Comment: Thank you for the replies, but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have bi-directional relationship between entities `A` and `B` then you need to maintain the relationship in your Java code as well.

Based on your code, lets say:

`A.java`:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="attribute")
List<B> bObjs;
```

`B.java`:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
@JoinColumn
A attribute;
```

Then to maintain the relationship in Java code you need to set on both sides like this:

```
a.setBObjs(listOfBs);
b.setA(a);
```

Then you can call `session.update(a)`, in this way hibernate will be able to save the entities correctly.

Comment: Does the JoinColumn annotation mandotory? If not, I did exaclty like you showed in your reply.

Comment: If you remove the JoinColumn then hibernate creates a Join table by default, so it is not mandatory. Can you show the exact code that you have tried and also post your entities to the question?